# ERR_CONNECTION_FAILED on Chrome/IE after 20 minutes of working when internet is still connected

Tags: windows, google-chrome, react-native, expo

Hoping this is the right place to ask this. I'm trying to learn React Native and I'm using Expo as my medium for deployment, but I'm finding that I'm literally getting 20 minutes at a time before my browser fails to connect with the error code ERR_CONNECTION_FAILED. I've tried the following:

- `netsh winsock reset`, then the related `ipconfig` commands for flushing DNS settings
- Clearing browser caches
- Updating drivers

I'm at my wits end as the only thing that completely solves it is restarting my laptop, which for obvious reasons isn't feasible every 20 minutes, so I'm hoping somebody can help.

Answer (score 11):

I'm experiencing the same issue with Expo in this environment:

- Windows 10, version 1909 (OS build 18363.476)
- using WSL (Windows Subsystem for Linux) with Ubuntu 18.04 LTS

These links were useful to learn why this is happening:

- https://github.com/expo/expo-cli/issues/99
- https://github.com/microsoft/WSL/issues/2913
- https://github.com/microsoft/WSL/issues/3951

In essence, this issue seems to be due to a problem with WSL.  Per a post in the first link, I tried the alternative to restarting the computer and it worked - it made the ERR_CONNECTION_FAILED problems disappear...for 20 minutes.  That alternative is as follows:

1. WIN+R -> services.msc
2. Find LxssManager
3. Right-click -> Restart

This restarts the WSL service which also means that the WSL instance that was running gets terminated.  This is less than ideal, but at least a computer restart is avoided.  The third link says this WSL problem is fixed in Windows Insider Build 18890.

I am now considering spinning up a VM to run Ubuntu instead of trying to use WSL for Expo projects.

Comment: Follow up - I did end up creating a VM to run Ubuntu and it was well worth the time to figure out how to get it setup and working.  Expo runs fine in the VM environment.

Comment: Thanks, you save my day

Comment: Thank you. I've been struggling with this for months. Never thought it was WSL.

Answer (score 0):

I uninstalled the latest Windows updates, and the problem has not surfaced since.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).